# Huge performance difference with querying a large table between join and multiple selects

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very large table with billions of rows. The following statements return the same result, but the first one (2 step query) took 22 seconds while the second one (table join) took 3 minutes.

ColID is the Identity column with primary key
An index is created based on colA and colB

---

```
select @valA = colA, @valB = colB 
from LargeTable 
where colID = 1234

select top 1000 * 
from LargeTable
where colA = @valA
  and colB = @valB
```

---

```
select top 1000 a.* 
from LargeTable a
     join LargeTable b on a.colA = b.colA
                      and a.colB = b.colB
where b.colID = 1234
```

From Comment : Upload the query plan https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJbHzoCKM

Comment: Query plans are probably going to be useful here: [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Comment: Table definition including indexes?

Comment: The second one will suffer from the optimizer having limited opportunity to correctly estimate the number of rows that will be returned, nor can it optimize seeking to them -- it can't know that the values it gets from the row with `colID` `1234` happen to be selective. There are probably ways to work around that without resorting to two separate queries, but yes, query plans are going to be insightful here.

Comment: Upload the query plan :https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJbHzoCKM

Comment: I'm guessing you want the fastest result with only 1 query?

Comment: That is not the query plan for that query.  `where b.id in (413241019,413858679)` is a different query.

Comment: Updated the plan:https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkocujRKf

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. The index I created has 4 columns, and the first column is not in the query at all, therefore the whole index is not used.

I dropped and recreated the index with first column removed, and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The plan uploaded does at least show the problem, the hash join. The hash table is being created using the rows returned from OptionArchive b based on the ID (That's the clustered index seek).

You have an index on option_type and expiration? (You specified only 2 columns in the index in the question), but the query is selecting a.mid_bid_ask and also joining on 3 columns (strike, option_type, expiration), so I suspect it has decided to 'tip' from seek to scan (and thus change from Nested Loop / Index Seek + Row ID Lookup) to the Hash + Scan, to ensure it is getting the field it needs.

That could be tested as a theory relatively easily, include mid_bid_ask in the non-clustered index.

It does not help that the query in the question + schema information does not match the query used to generate the plan though, we still do not know what the indexes are properly yet.

The Plan itself, in XML version is advising us of the missing index it believes it wants :

```
 <MissingIndexes>
              <MissingIndexGroup Impact="99.0357">
                <MissingIndex Database="[Quotes]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[OptionArchive]">
                  <ColumnGroup Usage="EQUALITY">
                    <Column Name="[expiration]" ColumnId="5"/>
                    <Column Name="[strike]" ColumnId="6"/>
                    <Column Name="[option_type]" ColumnId="7"/>
                  </ColumnGroup>
                  <ColumnGroup Usage="INCLUDE">
                    <Column Name="[mid_bid_ask]" ColumnId="27"/>
                  </ColumnGroup>
                </MissingIndex>
              </MissingIndexGroup>
            </MissingIndexes>
```

So that supports the notion of the covering index (including mid_bid_ask) and that the existing index may only cover 2 of the 3 columns.

Comment: What query plan?

Comment: He pasted a link to the plan as a comment, I'll edit into the question

Comment: But that is not the same query as the question.  Not just names are different.  The in clause is not in the question.

Comment: @paparazzo - yes, agreed, which I included as a point in my answer to far, I think the NC index is on 2 columns, the plan is identifying a missing index on the 3.

Comment: I don't understand this: "since it does not know what it is joining to on OptionArchive a", the join condition says this:join OptionArchive b on a.strike=b.strike and a.option_type=b.option_type and a.expiration=b.expiration

Comment: @ilcu2018 - I've edited, but I don't think it knows the quantity of data it needs to join on potentially, or it thinks it is too high so it swaps strategies, since you simplified the real code to an example for the question, in that simplification you have altered the actual problem in the process.

Comment: I was trying to simply the question by using LargeTable and colA,colB etc. All columns in the query are included in the index

Comment: Then the index is not a covering index, and it looks like it is hitting the tipping point. Include the selected field as an include column and it should start using the index instead of the clustered index scan (table scan in effect)